# different between text-align:center and margin auto?

Tags: css

I'm still new in css.
I know that

```
text-align:center;
```

and

```
margin:auto;
```

put the element in the center.
but what is the exact different between them ?
Thanks In advance.

Comment: `text-align: center` will center inline and inline-block content inside of the parent element that `text-align` is applied to. So that affects the children of an element. `margin: auto` when combined with a `width` that is less than 100% will center a block level element horizontally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well
That’s depends on what every property of them work.
For the `margin:` it’s give the specified value for the edges of the element.
For example:

```
margin: 5px;
```

Will give the element an **edge of 5px** each side.
So for example when you use
 `margin:0 auto;` 
It gives the element **0px edge** from the top and the bottom. And give it **auto equal edges** from left and right. So it will move to the center.

For `text-align: center;` 
This is most used with a **text** as its name. you can align the text left,right or center using it.

Answer (score 2):

text-align: center will center the contents of the container, while margin: auto will center the container itself.

Answer (score 0):

Margin: auto; will horizontally center the element contained within the container.
text-align : center; will put the contents of element center but the element itself will wont move.